# What are the leading CF alternatives available for Coldfusion + Flex integration?

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion

(Possible alternatives being Adobe's CF, Bluedragon, Railo, etc.)

What would you use for Coldfusion middleware if you had the following requirements and major considerations:

- Flex front end (w/remoting via AMF)
- Free (or low cost enough for a non-profit side project)
- Large enough community and resources online to find assistance when needed
- Maturity (and confidence that a particular version of CF isn't going to turn legacy any time soon)
- MySql database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Adobe CF would tick all your boxes except your 'free' requirement. We use BlazeDS and Flex with it, it's mature, well supported and has a large friendly community. In short it works great.

However, in terms of the licence cost there is an argument that CF has a [lower cost of ownership](http://www.adrocknaphobia.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-competitive-comparison-to-java-asp-net-and-php) but if paying anything is a big no-no, then I'd look at Railo - it's pretty much up to CF 9 standard, it's got paid support if you get really stuck and it has some [active forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/railo).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Kindof a not-for-profit personal project, so yeah I could spend over 1k for CF, but Railo seems to be the winner.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is an another alternate for a back-end. It talks to MySQL and can do remoting with Flex. It does require a bit of configuration to get remoting work, but it does work.